# Getting the last element of a list in dart

Tags: list, dart

In dart, how to access the last element of a list?

```
var lst = ["element1" , "element2" , "element3"];
```

My list is dynamic.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

you can use `last` property for read/write, inherited-getter:

`last` is a returns the last element from the given list.

```
var lst = ["element1" , "element2" , "element3"];
lst.last // -> element3
```

or

```
lst[lst.length-1] //-> element3
```

Comment: The best one is lst[lst.length-1] way because  in the "last" property ,it loops through the list until the last element is got , so it will be slower way.

Comment: @AvisekSSarma It depends on the collection type and implementation. If the collection elements are accessible by index there will be the same call for lst[lst.length-1]

Comment: @AvisekSSarma "The last element of a list can be modified, unlike an `Iterable`. A `list.last` is equivalent to `theList[theList.length - 1]`, both for getting and setting the value." from https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/List/last.html

Answer (score 0):

```
    **//Dart Code: Find 1st, Last, 2nd last and 3rd last value in Array**

void main() {

  List l1 = [1, 8, 5, 3, 0, 6, 7, 2, 9, 4,];
  
  print('Our original Array: $l1');

  // Sorting an array

  l1.sort();
  
  print('After sorting and Array: $l1');
  
  //Now we find the first, last, 2nd and 3rd last values of array
  
  var first = l1.first;

  print('Last value of Array: $first');
  
  var last = l1.last;

  print('Last value of Array: $last');
  
  var last2 =l1[l1.length-2];

  print('Last value of Array: $last2');
  
  var last3 =l1[l1.length-3];

  print('Last value of Array: $last3');
  
}
```